# Why does my log in info is missing after my RedirectToAction call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

In my asp.net MVC 4.6 application, after I logged in the site, I need to call `RedirectToAction` to call another controller, but the current log in data is lost before reaching another controller. However, the data is not lost if I run it in Anonymous authentication is enabled. But I can not make the Anonymous Authentication enabled. 
Here is the log on method in my AccountController class:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ValidateLogOn(userName, password) == false)
    {
         return View();
    }
    FormsAuthenticationService.SignIn(userName, false);
    IVtrsUser currentUser = MembershipService.Get(userName);
    if (currentUser.IsPasswordExpired)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) == false)
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Calendar");
    }
}
```

From the debug, I can see the two services have set the current user properly:

```
FormsAuthenticationService.SignIn(userName, false);
IVtrsUser currentUser = MembershipService.Get(userName);
```

But after the code excuated to the CalendarController as below:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class CalendarController : Controller
{ ...
```

The user signed in data such as Role = "Admin" is lost, which causes the following code in `CalendarController` is wrong, and is not execute the `Index()` method of `CalendarController`, Can anybody help me why this user login data is lost in Anonymous Authentication is Disabled mode? and the user data is remaining when Anonymous Authentication is enabled mode?
Add more , there is related codes:

```
public IFormsAuthenticationService FormsAuthenticationService { get; private set; }
```

and this is `IFormsAuthenticationService`:

```
namespace VTRS.WebApp.Controllers.Common
{
    public interface IFormsAuthenticationService
    {
        void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
        void SignOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you issuing a cookie once the user is authenticated? Normally done via [SetAuthCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd(v=vs.110).aspx). If you are setting the cookie, make sure it is being presented back by the browser.

Comment: What is `FormsAuthenticationService.SignIn()` and how is it adding the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`

Comment: That is good point, I don't think there is ForsAuthenticationTicket added. I have updated original post to add other source codes you asked, thanks

Comment: The thing is that the same codes work when I Enabled Anonymous Authentication in running Visual Studio. I mean the user signed in info such as Role is available when transfer another controller: CalendarController.

Comment: If your guys think the services I wrote is not working properly for keeping user logging data, then please let me know what is the standard or best way to keep user log in data, then I can modify my service or rewrite the code to keep the user log in data. thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

> please let me know what is the standard or best way to keep user log
>   in data, then I can modify my service or rewrite the code to keep the
>   user log in data.

In ASP.NET MVC, you want to use ***ASP.NET OWIN Cookie Middleware*** instead of FormAuthentication.

### [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs)

```
private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public void SignIn(User user)
{
    IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
    };

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

    IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
}

public void SignOut()
{
    IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
}
```

## [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Startup.cs)

You also need to configure Startup for all those to happen.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApplication.Startup))]
namespace YourApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can start using `[Authorize]` attribute in Controller and Action methods.

```
[Authorize]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

*Here is [my sample application at GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin) which uses AD for Authentication. But the core pieces are OwinAuthenticationService.cs and Startup.cs.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems the code is not that easy to digest, I need a bit time to learn how to implement it to my logic. I may need to start searching a simple example first.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Win: What is the difference between this service and  FormsAuthenticationTicket  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user2949042 FormAuthentication is a 15 years old technology. If you use ASP.NET MVC, you want to use OWIN Middleware, so that you can migrate to ASP.NET Core easily in the future. In ASP.NET Core, almost everything go throws middleware.